# Как определить координаты ячейки таблицы?

Tags: swift

Есть UITableView, надо определить координаты определённой ячейки на экране. Координаты должны быть относительно координат экрана. Как это сделать?

Или или же ещё лучше было бы узнать координаты определённого элемента в нужной ячейки относительно экрана. Но если это сложно, то хотя бы координаты ячейки.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение.

```swift
    func getElementCoordinate(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGPoint {
        let cellRect = mTableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) //Получаем область нужной ячейки
        let y = cellRect.origin.y //Получаем y координату относительно всего контента таблицы (сумма высот всех ячеек до нужной нам ячейки)
        let contentOffset = mTableView.contentOffset //смещение контента таблицы относительно начального нулевого положения
        let y_coordinate = y - contentOffset.y //чистая y координата ячейки относительно экранных координат
        let cell = mTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! TableViewCell //Достаём нужную ячейку
        let x_coordinate = cell.button_m.frame.origin.x //Получаем координаты нужного элемента относительно ячейки по оси x
        return CGPoint(x: x_coordinate, y: y_coordinate)
    }
```

где mTableView это собственно сама таблица, в которой нужно находить координаты,
TableViewCell класс ячейки для этой таблицы
button_m в этой ячейке это кнопка.